# Bootstrap 3 grid layout push/pull columns fail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building my first bootstrap grid layout and as I've read over and over I need to make the grid Mobile first, so I did this. Now I'm trying to make sure that the grid I have made is being adapted in bigger screens the way I want, and this includes different positioning for alot of my columns. Unfortunately even though I have tried to find ways to do this I have not succeeded in my plan. I hope someone here can help. This is my grid, obviously this positioning on mobile is correct and on small and bigger horrible since I havent done push and pull:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">7</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rVnN.png

```
[      2      ][              5               ]
[      1      ][         3         ][    4    ]
[      6      ][         3         ][    4    ]
[                      7                      ]
```

I hope anyone who is well experienced with this can help me build up my grid to achieve this. Otherwise I will probably have to add more blocks (some double ones) and hide them in the media queries where I want them positioned differently.

Comment: This isn't possible, the _push_ and _pull_ css classes can only move columns horizontally, they'll never wrap to another line. You could however duplicate the contents of the columns and have a layout for mobile and one for larger screens. (btw you should always have a `.row` div between the `.container` and the column classes)

Comment: Thanks ckujjer, I've thought as much. I'm trying to figure out my design now by duplicating the contents and making the mobile and larger screens layout. However I'm having small issues yet with either the elements for mobile not hiding or my desktop items not hiding. I'll continue trying tomorrow to see if I get any further,

Comment: What are your target browsers?  Flexbox can do this but you need a different strategy for IE9 and lower (JS polyfill likely).

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe what you had in mind https://jsfiddle.net/9urovfLa/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 blue"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 yellow"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 green"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 red"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 black"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 blue"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 green"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 yellow"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 black"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is indeed what I need for my desktop design but does not work on mobile. Since the ordering is not correct now (the above grid is written desktop first instead of mobile first.